# How do I edit a Kendo Grid DataSource Object?

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have in my View the following:

```
 columns.Bound(o => o.line.ApprovalBy.UserDisplayName)
 columns.Bound(o => o.line.ItemNumber)
```

Using JQuery, I am able to edit the Item Number line with the following:

```
('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.at(0).line.ItemNumber = 155
```

However, when I try to edit Approval By which is by default set to null with the following:

```
('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.at(0).line.ApprovalBy = {UserID: 50}
```

It returns an "undefined" in the grid for some reason.
When I try to edit an object that has been initialized previously, it would be able to work:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.line.Vehicle.Color);

('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.at(0).line.Vehicle.Color = "red";
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this example will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.408/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
 selectable: "multiple cell",
 allowCopy: true,
 columns: [{
  field: "productName"
 }, {
  field: "category"
 }, {
  field: "a.id"
 }, {
  field: "a.name"
 }],
 dataSource: [{
  productName: "Tea",
  category: "Beverages",
  a: {
   id: 1,
   name: "1"
  }
 }, {
  productName: "Coffee",
  category: "Beverages",
  a: {
   id: 2,
   name: "2"
  }
 }, {
  productName: "Ham",
  category: "Food",
  a: {
   id: 3,
   name: "3"
  }
 }, {
  productName: "Bread",
  category: "Food",
  a: {}
 }]
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
 var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
 dataSource.at(0).productName = "Tet";
 dataSource.at(3).a = {
  id: 4,
  name: "4"
  };
 grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
});
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```